# Distinguish between a sigalrm generated by the timer and a sigalrm generated by the user

Tags: c, linux, kill, alarm

I am trying to find a way to make a program work properly, which means that the program must get a sigalrm every 10 seconds until 100 seconds.

If I type the command kill -alrm program_process_pid, this sigalrm must be totally ignored so the program would not be affected by it. It must work as it is expected to.

I have read that the alarm() function returns the number of seconds until the previous programmed alarm finishes. I didn't find a way to do it yet, and it partially works.

Does anybody have an idea? Anything would be appreciated

Comment: You cannot distinguish between them (at best you can check the time to see if the alarm should have come in). A user is free to send any signal they want to their own processes, and regardless of the source, a signal is a signal.

Answer (score 1):

Just keep track of when you want to wake up, and set a new timer if it goes off early.

In pseudocode, the alarm handler would do:

```
if wakeupTime is not null:
  if currentTime < wakeupTime:
    alarm (wakeupTime - currentTime)
  else:
    start_processing
    wakeupTime = null
```

This way, it doesn't matter whether the process receives spurious SIGALRMs, and it also handles clock shifts better.

Answer (score 1):

The `alarm()` function will return nonzero if the previously scheduled alarm has not yet fired, so in your signal handler, you can call `alarm(0)` to (1) cancel the previous alarm, and (2) determine whether it needed to be cancelled. If it returns a nonzero value, you know the alarm was externally generated, and you can call `alarm` again with the value it returned to reschedule your own.

I'm not sure if `alarm` will return zero if the alarm has fired but the signal is queued behind an externally generated alarm, though (that is, if the external alarm signal was generated *just* before yours fired). The POSIX standard is a little vague about that.

Comment: if there are two `SIGALRM` queued, does it really matter which one was externally generated?  Both handlers will run after the scheduled alarm time.

Comment: That's a good point. The first invocation would see a return value of 0, and the second one wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to avoid this is not use `alarm` which only generates `SIGALRM`.

There are POSIX timers that allow you to specify what signal to send and to even differentiate different signals within that signal type.  See [timer_create](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/timer_create.html), [timer_settime](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/timer_settime.html), [timer_delete](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/timer_delete.html), etc.

Note there is something of a learning curve involved with these so you'll need to read and do your research first but this is really what you want if you want to avoid a cluster hack job.